# How to remove warning text beside my code in Flutter's Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a new Flutter learner, and this is kinda annoy me, I think the "Problems" tab under is fully understand, I don't want to see warning next to my code. Is there a way I can disable or hide it? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: The widget `Text("My Text")` should become `const Text("My Text")` since the content of the `Text` widget doesn't get modified. Second, `RaisedButton` is deprecated, so you should use `ElevatedButton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hey, In visual studio code you can do minute changes.**

**Step1:**

Press ctrl+shift+p , a command pallet will open
[image]

**Step2:**

Type *settings.json* and click on *Open Settings (JSON)*
a file will open
[image]

**step3:**

Add this lines in that

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": true
}
```

****After this whenever you save, const will be added automatically.**

**Note: Sometimes you might get error because after saving some widgets are prefixed with const but, sometimes when your values in widget get dynamic, there will be a error, so be careful.**

Answer (score 0):

[image]

disable this line or add source.fixAll to config.json

Comment: Please don't post code (or configuration!) as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your answer from getting deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are using some vscode plugin like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens to show code diagnostics.
Though that feature seems very useful to me incase you find that annoying you may disable it by going through your list of extensions.

Answer (score 0):

go to analysis_options.yaml file that is in your root directory .

paste the following lines :

```
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

linter:
  rules:
    prefer_const_constructors: false
    prefer_final_fields: false
    use_key_in_widget_constructors: false
    prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables: false
    prefer_const_constructors_in_immutables: false
    avoid_print: false
```